# Hibernate subquery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a problem in creating subqueries with Hibernate. Unfortunately the Subqueries class is almost entirely undocumented, so I have absolutely no clue how to convert the following SQL into a Hibernate Criteria:

```
SELECT id
FROM car_parts
WHERE car_id IN ( SELECT id FROM cars WHERE owner_id = 123 )
```

I was hoping the following would 'just work':

```
session.createCriteria(CarParts.class).add(eq("car.owner", myCarOwner));
```

but unfortunately it does not. So it seems I actually have to use the Subqueries class to create the Criteria. But I was unable to find a reasonable example though Google, so that leads me to asking it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create an alias for the "car" property before adding the eq expression like this:

```
session.createCriteria(CarParts.class)  
        .createAlias("car", "c")  
        .add(eq("c.owner", myCarOwner));
```

Answer (score 10):

Try Like this:

Table details): Category (id, name, desc, parentId, active)

```
    DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria
            .forClass(Category.class);
    subCriteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("parent"));
    subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", Boolean.TRUE));
    subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", categoryName));
    subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Category.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", Boolean.TRUE));
    criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("parent", subCriteria));
```

It will generate the query like:

```
select
    *
from
    Categories this_ 
where
    this_.active=1
    and this_.parentId = (
        select
            this0__.id as y0_ 
        from
            Categories this0__ 
        where
            this0__.parentId is null 
            and this0__.active=1
            and this0__.name='Health Plan'
    )
```

Good Luck!

-Rohtash Singh

Comment: criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("parent", subCriteria)); what is parent here?

Answer (score 0):

As first check the ORM configuration between Car and CarPart entities, usually you need the setup the relationship between them. After that try to execute the following code:

```
List result = session.createQuery("from " + CarPart.class.getName() + 
    " as parts join parts.car as car where car.owner = :myOwner")
    .setParameter("myOwner", 123)
    .list();
```