# Can HQL Select on the result set of another query?

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, hql

Can HQL Select on the result set of another query?
For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Table)
```

I can do it in SQL but when I tried like above in HQL, it just showed me syntax error "unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 22 ..."

Comment: I have same problem,Please suggest exact solution you used

Comment: It is better to use inner join with same table in this case, HQL cannot add sub-queries in from  clause

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HQL does support [subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries), however they can only occur in the select or the where clause.  The example you provide would best be wrote as a straight statement in HQL.  For example:

```
select count(*) from table t  (where table is the entity name)
```

If the query involves a more complicated statement than `(select * from Table)`, I would recommend putting this logic into a view and then creating an entity based off of this view.

> For databases that support subselects, Hibernate supports subqueries
>   within queries. A subquery must be surrounded by parentheses (often by
>   an SQL aggregate function call). Even correlated subqueries
>   (subqueries that refer to an alias in the outer query) are allowed.

**Example**

```
from DomesticCat as cat
where cat.name not in (
    select name.nickName from Name as name
)
```

Comment: Is there a Criteria equivalent?

Comment: @C_B, check this stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411287/hibernate-subquery)

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do subquery in `from` clause in HQL even if the database support it, I solved this problem by putting the query into the sql as a `store procedure`, then call the procedure in HQL. For example:

Insert the procedure into your sql:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_name`(
  `arg_name` INT,
) BEGIN
     your query here
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, if you use hibernate, call this procedure from java code as below:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL procedure_name(:arg_name)");
query.setParameter("arg_name", args);
List list = query.list();
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery as you desire is not possible. One way is using a distinct this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) FROM table t INNER JOIN t.list l
     WHERE t.status = 'ST1' AND l.status = 'ST2'"
```

I used the inner join to express a select repetition

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a view for my query, then created a model object for that.  Then it was trivial to create HQL queries for it.

My application doesn't have some of the performance requirements that others might, though, so I can get away with it.