# Hibernate unable to parse count() with upper()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, distinct, jpql

I have a table of Location entities with a **city** property of type String, and an **active** property of type Boolean.

For example, we have two entities with city "Derby" and "DERBY".  I need to return just one string entry for these two.

The following hql is parsed ok by Hibernate:

```
select distinct upper(l.city) from Location l where l.active = true
```

Hibernate is apparently unable to parse the following hql:

```
select count(distinct upper(l.city)) from Location l where l.active = true
```

Hibernate seems to throw an exception at the "upper" where it looks like it expects an alias or identifier.

The exact same select statement works fine as standard sql against our postgres database.

How else can I extract distinct rows of the upper-cased **city** property from Location?

Edit:  Here's the stack trace...

```
    [ERROR][20-08-2018 16:11:21,904][org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] :: line 1:28: expecting CLOSE, found '('
[ERROR][20-08-2018 16:11:21,905][org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] :: line 1:28: expecting CLOSE, found '('
line 1:28: expecting CLOSE, found '('
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aggregate(HqlBaseParser.java:4969)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4405)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:975)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3530)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3383)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2912)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2679)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2385)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2098)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1372)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.kn.mik.aetherserver.server.service.AetherServiceImpl.getUniqueCities(AetherServiceImpl.java:4237)
    at com.kn.mik.aetherserver.server.test.AetherServiceTest.testGetUniqueCities(AetherServiceTest.java:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
[ERROR][20-08-2018 16:11:21,912][org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] :: line 1:29: unexpected token: l
[ERROR][20-08-2018 16:11:21,912][org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] :: line 1:29: unexpected token: l
line 1:29: unexpected token: l
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1372)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.kn.mik.aetherserver.server.service.AetherServiceImpl.getUniqueCities(AetherServiceImpl.java:4237)
    at com.kn.mik.aetherserver.server.test.AetherServiceTest.testGetUniqueCities(AetherServiceTest.java:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: what if you rewrite query to `select count(distinct upper(l.city)) as cnt from Location l where l.active = true`

Comment: No difference - the hql doesn't make use of the new _cnt_ alias anyway...????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [JPA 2.1 Specification Final Release](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> BNF Grammar of the Java Persistence Query Language:
>
> ```
> aggregate_expression ::=
>     {AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM} ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
>     COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
>           single_valued_association_path_expression) |
>     function_invocation
> ```

So, you cannot use `UPPER()` like this in this case with `JPQL`.

You can use your working `sql` query with hibernate native query, for example:

```
public long getCount() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UPPER(l.city))"
            + " FROM location_table_name l WHERE l.active = true";

    return ((BigInteger) em.createNativeQuery(sql)
            .getSingleResult())
            .longValue();
}
```

***NOTE:***

If you have case insensitive `collation`, following `JPQL` should simply work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.city) FROM Location l WHERE l.active = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following query:

```
select l.city from Location l where l.active = true group by upper(l.city)
```

And then get the result size:

```
int numberOfCities = yourSession.createQuery(hqlSelect).getResultList().size();
```

Comment: Hi Christian - unfortunately the query you posted isn't legal.  The nearest to this is `select count(l.city) from Location l where l.active = true group by upper(l.city)` which will just return multiple rows containing the number of time each city appears in the table.

Comment: If the query isn't legal you might want to check the naming of your fields. `select u.name from User u where u.tutorialState = 1000 group by upper(u.name)` works fine on my setup. And yes, the query doesn't return the number you want. That's why you retrieve it afterwards by the size of your resultset. Another possible approach is highlighted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081864/7200161